What is the most reliable way to use libtorrent 2.0 from node?
I have a case where I have to download a torrent from a node (electron) app.
I've tried webtorrent, but it has more bugs than functionality. Well then, libtorrent exists. But the official node bindings are ancient, not maintained and I doubt they are compatible with 2.0 (please correct me if I'm wrong). So, there are a few options:

write my own bindings or perish trying
use the old, official ones, probably with an older version of the lib
generate new bindings using some weird tool like scapix
use official python bindings and then something like pythonia
treat libtorrent with emscripten? is it even possible?

What would be the most reliable (and - if possible - the simplest) choice in your opinion? Maybe there's a better alternative? Thank you in advance for any suggestions.
